# Map Accessors to Wrapped Object

Tags: ruby, hash, proxy, accessor

I have a flat Hash:

```
hash = Hash["prop_one" => 100, "prop_two" => 200, "prop_three" => 300]
```

I have wrapped it in a class, with the class exposing these values *to be read* through accessors:

```
class WrappedHash

  def prop_one
    config['prop_one']
  end

  def prop_two
    config['prop_two']
  end  

  def prop_three
    config['prop_three']
  end

  def initialize(config)
    self.config = config
  end

end
```

Is there a way to proxy requests for these properties to the hash without having to manually add accessors? (It's a big hash)

Comment: why not `{"prop_one" => 100, "prop_two" => 200, "prop_three" => 300`}?

Comment: Because We may be switching out where the property values come from, so I don't want everything referencing an object. Rather it was a class.

Comment: No, I mean `Hash[...]`, why use this convoluted way to build hash. Just out of curiousity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) if you have dynamic hash keys or [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) if keys are static and performance is important.

OpenStruct can be converted back to Hash by its `marshal_dump` method

Comment: Thanks. That looks great. But seems there is no way to make the properties read-only. Just edited the question to underline the fact I want them to be read-only.

Answer (score 3):

You can also implement method_missing method. It is invoked by Ruby when obj is sent a message it cannot handle.

```
class WrappedHash
  def method_missing(methId)
    config[methId.to_s]
  end
end
```